# child and parent both event handler. possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

my UI is `<li><a href='#'>hello</a></li>`

anchor tag has already event handler i.e. `click(function(){})`
I want to give another click function to list items but its not working

Update - I only want to give event handler to list items not anchor tag as parent

Please suggest me

Comment: post your html if you want a good answer.

Comment: Do the same to the list items what you have done before to the anchor tag.

Comment: Have you tried moving the click handler to the <li> tag, and then checking the event to see which element was actually clicked, and then handling it that way?  In fact, for best performance, you would want to give the list tag (e.g., <ul>) the click handler and do the same thing -- see which list item, anchor, etc. was clicked in the handler.

Comment: What do you mean by clicking `li` without clicking the `a` tag. `<li><a href='#'>hello</a></li>` would render `li` as same as `a` tag which make it very hard to click unless you have (2+)px padding or a border in li. In anycase, if you click on the padding/border.. it wouldn't call the link click handler.

Comment: do both things in your click function?

Comment: below is my code 
<li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>

I want if click happens to anchor tag corresponding details appear 
if click happens to list class of list changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. If you have this HTML

```
<li> <a href="#">Hello</a></li>
```

Then you can have this jquery handlers:

```
       $("li").click(function () {
            alert("li clicked");
        });

        $("li > a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert("anchor clicked");
            return false;
        });
```

Notice that you need the "return false;".

Hope this helps,
-covo

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery's `event.stopPropagation()` method in the click event for your anchor tag to prevent the anchor event from bubbling up.

Like so:

```
$('your existing anchor selector').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    //Your other code
});
```